# AWS Backup Not Transitioning to Cold Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

Our AWS costs are increasing at a steady rate each month. Looking into it, I found that none of our backups are transitioning to Cold Storage, even though every plan has a transition period set and the retention in cold storage is configured way past the required 90 days.

I have read the documentation and can not see where I am going wrong. Any ideas?

[image: The Backup Rule Configuration]

Here is what is in the Vault, every snapshot taken says the same
[image: Vault screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to transition AMI when only EFS are supported.

> Each lifecycle rule contains an array of transition objects specifying how long in days before a recovery point transitions to cold storage, or is deleted. As of now, the transition to cold storage is ignored for all resources except for Amazon EFS.

From here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/automating-backups-and-optimizing-backup-costs-for-amazon-efs-using-aws-backup/